# how to make show more footer with progressbar at bottom of listview?

Tags: android

I have a fragment which contain listview that have some data from server and I am adding progressbar footer at bottom of listview when user scroll down listview a progress bar at bottom of listview is shown to user and send server request and add some more data in listview ,problem is that when scroll to end progressbar is also visible but sending server request back to back .How can I archeive this problem.

here is my code for listview scroll

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount-1 && totalItemCount != 0) {
        if (!isloading) {
            // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
            isloading = true;
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

                sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                loadmoreData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and here is my code for sending request when progressbar footer is shown to user in listview

```
public void loadmoreData() {

    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        Log.d("CAppList:",sz_RecordCount);
        Log.d("Capplist:",sz_LastCount);
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        System.out.println("Server Request:-" + json);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CServerAPI.m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("Response:-" + response);
                try {
                    JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                        item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                        item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                        item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                        item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                        if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {
                            s_oDataset.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    isloading=false;
                    m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());
                        m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                        requestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error:-" + error);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                }
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is maintain a flag for network request and one for noMoreDataLeft.

```
boolean noMoreDataLeft;
boolean requestGoingOn;
```

Everytime when you make a network call just change the value of requestGoingOn to true. And whene you come to know throught your api that there is no more data on server make the noMoreDataLeft true.

Now define two constants for show loading and data row -

```
private final static int TYPE_LOADING = 0;
private final static int TYPE_DATA = 1;
```

Now -

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size() + (requestGoingOn && !isNoMoreDataLeft ? 1 : 0);
}
```

It will add a more row when request is going on. Now you just need to check the current position if it is more than data.size then return type as loading.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position >= data.size() ? TYPE_LOADING : TYPE_DATA;
    }
```

That's it, now itemType will be available so you can decide which view you need to show. Hope it will help :)

Comment: PLEASE EDIT MY CODE